# how to share my slack App to Other Workspaces with Public Distribution way

Tags: sockets, slack, workspace, mode

I created a slack app with socket mode and I have one question about distributing my app:

1. If I want to publicly distribute my app, I know that " Apps using Socket Mode are not currently allowed in the public Slack App Directory (https://slack.com/apps) . ", I want to confirm, under socket mode, can I make the app publicly distributed without submitting to app directory? Or as long as I intend to publicly distribute my app, regardless of submitting it to app directory or not, I can't use socket mode and must enable HTTP Request URLs?
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Socket app 'Public Distributed' without submitting it to App Directory.

Go to 'Manage Distribution' page and make sure all the required fields are checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because even if you want to distribute not via Slack App Directory, You still need to provide the Redirect URI. Socketmode only covers the Request URL, so you still need to provide the Redirect URI.